# Matching URLs with other characters around

Tags: regex

I need a regex pattern to match URLs in a complicated environment.

An URL would be in this position:

```
[url=http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php:32p0eixu]TEST[/url:32p0eixu]
```

(That's just a sample URL)

I need to match the URL until the *colon*, the colon and the code after that should be ignored. There are so many URLs out there and I'm not that experienced to create a pattern to match everything from *http://* to *:*

As I said, everything else should be ignored, left away, except the URL which I need to store in a variable.

Could someone help me create such a pattern? My tries were matching the URL above, but when I put in more complicated URLs, they wouldn't match.

This is the pattern I've created. It works with simple URLs, but not with the complicated ones:

```
http(s)?://[A-Za-z0-9.,/_-]+
```

I'm not very good in regex, I'm still learning.

Thank you.

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Is the url supposed to include the `http://` if it's there?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll post my try now. @ExplosionPills It should match both: http and https

Comment: @Dugi Also, what language are you using? Different regex engines support different features and sometimes have different syntax.

Comment: What characters can be contained in the postfix after the URL (32p0eixu)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should do it for you.

```
\[url=(.*?):[a-zA-Z0-9]*\]
```

Run against your test data:

```
[url=http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php:32p0eixu]TEST[/url:32p0eixu]
```

This will return the URL in capture group 1.

Assuming PHP (since your test URL is for the PHP manual), you'd use this with `preg_match` like this:

```
$value = "[url=http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php:32p0eixu]TEST[/url:32p0eixu]";
$pattern = "/\[url=(.*?):[a-zA-Z0-9]*\]/";
preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Output:

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
```

This will also work against URLs which contain colons in them, such as:

```
http://www.php.net:8080/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
http://www.php.net/manual/us:en/function.preg-replace.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Below regex will give you the url part before colon:

```
\[url=((http|https)?://)?[^\:]+
```

Comment: Let me know your most complex url you have tried. It would help to generate appropriate regex.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
`^(http(s)?:\/\/)?[^]^(^)^ ]+`